# Title for young girl

Tags: names, forms-of-address

If Master is used as a title for writing the name of a young boy (as in Master William), what is used before the name of a young girl?

Comment: "Master" is formal and not commonly used, at least not in the United States. Instead we would use the boy's full name.  There are venues that use formal titles, but these will sometimes use the child's first name ("Master Bruce") and sometimes the last name ("Master Wayne").  Either way, it's "Miss" for girls, ("Miss Diana" / "Miss Prince").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Miss' can be used before the name of a young girl because 'Miss' is a title for any girl (irrespective of her age) who is unmarried. Another title is 'Ms'if the girl wants her to be called by, but usually, 'Miss' is preferable.

More information is [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091122082632AAwAqlW).

Hope this helps.